# Webpack bundle analyzer shows different chunk size form Chrome Netwrok tab

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-devtools, webpack-bundle-analyzer

I'm trying to figure out next thing:
When I run webpack-bundle-analyzer locally for the prod build it shows one size (7.65MB) in gzipped mode for one of the assets:

[image: webpack-bundel-analyzer-output]

But when I ran the production build and check Chrome's Network tab I see different size it downloads for the same chunk, also gziped (9.6MB):

[image: Network-panel-size]

[image: network-details]

I wonder where this difference comes from.
The only idea that comes to my mind, is that `webpack-bundle-analyzer` has different compressing logic for gzip from `ngnix` but not sure that's the case.

I would appreciate any ideas on this matter, thanks!

Comment: It may be a bug. You can make a gz file yourself and compare the size.